# using DirectX with c# on visual studio

Tags: c#, directx

I am new to C# and trying to follow a tutorial in a beginners C# book I have, it is a few years old and in one of the tutorials the author uses:

```
using  Microsoft.DirectX;

using Microsoft.DirectX.Direct3D;
```

I have installed the DirectX sdk june 2010, 
I am using virtual studio 2012 and have tried to add a reference to any DirectX that I have in the reference manager but to no avail.
Is the  tutorial just too outdated or  am I doing something wrong and if so what is  an alternative?

Also I have seen references to SharpDX on other posts about directx and c# but I don't understand the relation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) is a set of tools with a managed runtime environment provided by Microsoft.
Check [Microsoft Indie Developers site](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US). There are some tutorials about first steps on XNA: [link](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/tutorial/2dgame/getting_started).

And I think you don't need DirectX SDK:

> If you’re using Windows 7 or Windows Vista, there’s only one step you need to take: Simply Install the Windows Phone Developer Tools. That’s all you need to get started! XNA Game Studio is included in the tools, and will work for Windows, Xbox 360, and Windows Phone 7.

I hope Windows 8 included =)

Happy coding!

Comment: I actually discovered XNA yesterday, I have to say it is pretty cool.I was going to update to windows 8 but they want 275 euros to upgrade from windows 7 pro so I think I will wait a while. Thanks for  the link.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "official" DirectX for C#. You can load by by yourself, using C++ DirectX librarries and call them from C#. But better way is to try some library. About two years ago, I was using SlimDX (not sure, if its still updated)

Comment: How do I add external Libraries?, I am used to python so a bit lost as to how to do it on C#

Comment: You can use method called "P/Invoke". There are plenty of materials, just use google. But I would not recomend to go this way. It will be pretty difficult to get DirectX working properly.

Comment: do you mean not to use DirectX at all?

Comment: I mean use already existing port of DirectX to C# (like SlimDX or by you mentioned SharpDX)